# How does Ascending work?

Tags: clicker-heroes

The next upgrade I am likely to get is "ASCENSION" for Amenhotep.  The mouseover text on the ability says it restarts the game and gives a single hero soul.

Does anything else cross over (heroes, gold, achievements, etc.)?

When would be the best time to Ascend?  Should I wait until I unlock all the heroes or buy all their abilities?  I'm on level 85 now (not yet beat the boss), should I wait until a specific level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you ascend, you'll receive 1 hero soul per 2000 hero levels. (unless changed)
Basically if you have a total of 5310, you'd get 2 hero souls.

Before you'd get cooldown reductions, damage, more gold and so on. But now I believe that you only get a % of damage. (you can read if you hover over the hero souls text)
If I'm correct, it's 10% extra DPS per hero soul that you have.

I think I did my first ascension around level 100, but like I said, you had more/better extra stuff by then.

I'd say do an ascension whenever you feel that you are ready, then try to get as far as you can, without spending ages on each level, then repeat.

It's hard to say when the best level for ascension is but yer, I lost my savefile and I got pretty damn far. :3

Best of luck to you.

Comment: Ancients also cross over.

Comment: It seems the point of the early game is to ascend often to get hero souls so you can go through again faster and farther.  In early game, as soon as you can ascend you should spend all your gold on leveling heroes to get as many souls as possible and, if close to level 100 and able to beat the boss, get the free soul from beating it.

Comment: Beating level 100 also unlocks the automatic progression switch, which remains unlocked forever and across ascensions.

Answer (score 5):

When you ascend, you get +1 Hero Soul for each 2000 hero levels you have. If you have beaten Omeet, the boss for level 100, you will get an additional soul. If you beat any Primal bosses, you will receive their bonus Hero Souls as well.

What survives an ascension: Hero Souls, Ancients, and Gildings.

For every hero soul you have, you do +10% more DPS. Also, hero souls are needed to summon ancients and level them up.

Ancients grant you a special power of some kind. To summon an Ancient requires hero souls. To level them up requires more hero souls.

Once you are past level 100, you can earn a gilded hero. You do this by beating a divisible by 10 level for your very first time. That is, beating level 110 for the very first time will earn you a gilded hero. The second time you beat it, nothing. Gilded heroes do +50% more damage than their normal counterparts, and a hero may be gilded multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I did my 1st ascension on lvl 98, and get 3 heroes souls. Increase the lvl of low heores to at least 500 to increase the number of heores souls. The game will become easier and you'll be able to go forward quickly.